# how to write this query in correct syntax?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT collegename(SELECT allotement.collegename,dean.id 
FROM dean,allotement 
WHERE allotement.city=dean.city
 &&dean.collegename<>allotement.collegename
 &&dean.id<>allotement.id)as  t WHERE id=1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT collegename from (
SELECT allotement.collegename, dean.id 
FROM dean,allotement WHERE allotement.city=dean.city
and dean.collegename<>allotement.collegename 
and dean.id<>allotement.id)
as t WHERE id=1
```

A few points to note here:

1. Treat sub-query as a table source from which you are retrieving the data. Thus, you need a `from` in the first line.
2. `&&` doesn't work in SQL. You have to write `and` instead.
3. In your case, writing `as t` is optional.

You can actually go through a pretty good [link](http://cse.unl.edu/~sscott/ShowFiles/SQL/CheatSheet/SQLCheatSheet.html) which I generally use to follow mySQL syntax, as it's a bit confusing, considering the fact that different SQL databases have a slight variation in syntax and functions available.

You can refer to the official mySQL docs [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax.html) as well, if in case required.

Comment: Please, comment your improvements.

Comment: @Suncatcher sorry, just did. :)

Comment: Both && and || do work see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/logical-operators.html#operator_and However, your use of AND is a much better approach as it is the more formal SQL syntax.

Comment: Oh thnks @Clinton, didn't know that.. Now this is confusing actually: || in db2 is used for concatenation.. There should he one, unified , SQL syntax..!

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS**: We can simply achieve that in following simple way even we don't need sub query for that:

```
SELECT a.collegename, d.id 
FROM dean AS d
INNER JOIN allotement AS a ON a.city = d.city
 AND d.collegename <> a.collegename
 AND d.id <> a.id
WHERE d.id = 1
```

Comment: It's my pleasure.